# Partial Differential Equation with boundary dirichlet conditions without solutions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, functional-equations, elliptic-operators

Let $\Omega$ a smooth and bounded domain, $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ and $L$ an uniform elliptic operator in divergence form. Consider the problem:
$$(1)
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  Lu=f \hspace{.4cm} \mbox{     in  } \Omega,\\
  u=0 \hspace{.4cm} \mbox{     in  } \partial\Omega.
 \end{array}
\right.$$
QUESTION: There exist uniform elliptic operator in divergence form $f$ such that the problem $(1)$ has no solution for every $f\neq 0$???

My attempt: The idea is using Fredhölm Alternative, considering the adjoint homogeneous problem:
$$(H)
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  Lu=0 \hspace{.4cm} \mbox{     in  } \Omega,\\
  u=0 \hspace{.4cm} \mbox{     in  } \partial\Omega.
 \end{array}
\right.$$
Fredhölm states that if $u\in A:=\left \{ u\in H_0^1(\Omega) | u  \mbox{ is solution of }  (H)\right \}$ then u is solution of $(1)$ if and only if: $$(u,f)_{L^2(\Omega)}=\int_\Omega uf=0, i.e. f\in A^\perp.$$
So I must show an operator $L$ such that for every $u\in A$ and  $f\in L^2(\Omega)\backslash \{0\}$ occurs:
$$(u,f)_{L^2(\Omega)}\neq 0.$$

I understand the theory but I don't know which operator I must use to prove the last statement. Every comment and idea would be so appreciated, thanks ♥

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $-\Delta$, i.e., there is $w\ne0$, $w\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ such that
$$
-\Delta w = \lambda w
$$
in the weak sense. Then set $L:= -\Delta - \lambda$. Then $w\in A$ and $A^\perp$ is not the whole space.